# I am solving a problem with recursion but I got an Tle error on my last test case,how can I optimize my code?

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

Here is my question :

Given an array of non-negative integers, you are initially positioned at the first index of the array.

Each element in the array represents your maximum jump length at that position.

Determine if you are able to reach the last index.

And here is my code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool canJump(vector<int>& nums) {
        int index=nums.size()-1;
        bool ans=dfs(nums,0);
        return ans;
    }
    bool dfs(vector<int>&nums,int start)
    {
        if(start>=0 && start<nums.size())
        {
            if(start == nums.size()-1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if(nums[start] == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if(start>=nums.size())
            {
                return false;
            }
            for(int i=1;i<=nums[start];i++)
            {
                bool check = dfs(nums,start+i);
                if(check == true)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

However I got tle on last test case:
Here is the last test case

How can I optimize my code?Please help

Thanks.

Comment: `Tea Lost Exception`? Please don't use acronyms that only people who use online programming contests will understand. Please also provide a [mre] with complete code, inputs and expected outputs

Comment: Rule of Thumb:  **T**ime **L**imit **E**xceeded errors usually mean that you are using a slow algorithm or implementation and there are faster algorithms that you should use.

Answer (score 0):

The bounds are essentially `N <= 10^5`, which means you must come up with an `O(n*log(n))` solution for this. Your DFS can be trivially reduced to `O(N^2)` if you memoize it, but it is significantly slower in its current non-memoized state. The idea behind this is you can use a data structure like a Fenwick tree (also known as a Binary Indexed Tree, or BIT) to store if a position can reach the end or not. Then, you can get the sum of a range in `O(log(n))` and update an element in `O(log(n))` as well. Then, you can define the input array to be `nums`, the array containing whether an index is possible to be `poss`, and the sum of `poss[x]` from `i` to `j` (including `j` but not `i`) to be `sum(poss, i, j)`. You can calculate `poss` via the following formula:

```
poss[n - 1] = 1
poss[i] = max(1, sum(poss, i, min(i + nums[i], n - 1)))
```

Comment: Can you please provide resources regarding BIT ? It would be quite helpful for me..Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding something, but this seems really simple to solve with a single iteration over the array (from end to begin).

- If you know that index `i` can reach the end, and you find out that you can reach index `i` from index `c`, then index `c` can also reach the end.
- If you can jump up to `n` steps, are at index `c` and know `i <= c + n`, then you can reach index `i`.
- If index `i` and index `j` can reach the end, and `i < j`, then it is enough if you reach `i`.

```cpp
bool CanReachEnd(std::vector<int> const & jumps)
{
    assert(jumps.size() > 0);
    std::size_t current = jumps.size() - 1;
    std::size_t lowest_can_reach_end = current;
    while (true)
    {
        assert(jumps[current] >= 0); // "non negative", unsigned would be better!
        if (current + jumps[current] >= lowest_can_reach_end)
        {
            lowest_can_reach_end = current;
        }
        if (current == 0) break;
        current -= 1;
    }
    assert(current == 0);
    return (lowest_can_reach_end == 0);
}
```

[(Demo)](https://ideone.com/e0EmU8)